# how to count no of nodes in using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

how to count number of  nodes in tree using php and mysql.

```
## id ## parent ## child ## 
    0     0          A
    1     0          B
    2     0          C
    3     2          D
    4     1          E
    5     1          F
    6     2          G
    7     3          H
    8     5          I
    9     5          J
   10     5          L
   11     5          M
   12     1          N
   13     0          O
   14     0          P
      A
    /   \
   B     C    
  / \   /  \
 E  F  D    G
```

How we can count sub node

condition A - 1st generation 2 only ( B, C) if finish this 2 count A go to create new tree

like as

```
   A
  / \
 O   P
```

how i give the condition.

Comment: Thoroughly read this link....
This might help you but u need to change your database table structure http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Comment: maybe you should rephrase your conditions. I don't really understand what your condition is to create a new tree.

Comment: because i need to count 6 sub notes, 2 is 1st generation and 4 is 2nd generation. is it possible to count nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of recursion. This is not easy in MySQL, so I think you can best do this with help of PHP. For instance, create a function like this:

```
function countNodes($rootNode)
{
   $result = 1; // The rootnode itself.

   // Query children of $rootnode. 
   // I leave this to you.

   foreach($subNode in $children)
     $result += countNodes($subNodes);

  return $result;
}
```

You see this function keeps calling itself for each of the children it finds under each node, effectively walking all the tree.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, Thanks for your reply, i will try to follow your instructions. Thanks,